# Finding the distribution of sample of exponential distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I'm having trouble with this problem:

If $Y_{1}...Y_n$ is a sample of the exponential distribution, with $\tau > 0$, then what is the distribution of $U = \frac{2\sum_{i=1}^{n}Y_{i}}{\tau}$

I know that the exponential distribution looks like $\frac{1}{\tau}e^\frac{-x}{\tau}$. However I could use some help on how to use that in finding the distribution of $U = \frac{2\sum_{i=1}^{n}Y_{i}}{\tau}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sum of two independent exponential random variables with the same decay constant is quite simple. Let $Z=Y_1+Y_2$. Its pdf is,
$$f_Z(z)=\int_0^\infty f_{Y_1}(y_1)f_{Y_2}(z-y_1)\,dy_1=
\int_0^\infty{1\over\tau}e^{-y_1/\tau}\mathbf{1}_{y_1\ge0}{1\over\tau}e^{-(z-y_1)/\tau}\mathbf{1}_{z-y_1\ge0}\,dy_1$$
This gives,
$$f_Z(z)={1\over\tau^2}\int_0^ze^{-z/\tau}\,dy_1={ze^{-z/\tau}\over\tau^2}$$
for $z\ge0$. Now do the same again by considering $W=Z+Y_3$ and you will see the pattern for arbitrary $n$. Finally apply the scaling factor $r={2\over\tau}$. If $U=rW$, then
$f_U(u)=f_W(w)/r$.